# Also display the model of computer allocated to the employee and the manager, how to do thi

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Display id, name, manager id and manager name of those employees who are allocated a computer and whose manager is also allocated a computer. Also display the model of computer allocated to the employee and the manager.
expected output: ID   ENAME            MGRID      MGRNAME            E_MODEL    M_MODEL
5    Ayaz Mohammad      1       James Potter          Edge      Vostro

Comment: `Also display the model of computer allocated to the employee and the manager, how to do thi` ... what is your difficulty? ... how to display? ... computer? ... employee? ... manager? ... allocation? ... etc, etc

Comment: Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can re-create the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select
    e.id, e.ename, e.mgrid, m.mgrname, e.e_model, m.m_model
from (
    select e.id, e.ename, e.manager mgrid, c.model e_model
    from employee e, computer c
    where e.compid = c.compid
) e, (
    select e.id mgrid, e.ename mgrname, c.model m_model
    from employee e, computer c
    where e.compid = c.compid
) m
where e.mgrid = m.mgrid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e1.id ID,e1.ename ENAME,e1.manager MGRID,e2.ename MGRNAME    
,c1.model E_MODEL ,c2.model M_MODEL    
 from employee e1 inner join employee e2    
 on e1.manager =e2.id    
 inner join computer c1 on e1.compid = c1.compid     
 inner join computer c2 on e2.compid=c2.compid
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm impressed. How did you know the structure of the [database] tables? I saw no such details in the question. By the way, the question does not meet SO guidelines according to: [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). As such, you shouldn't answer it as it just encourages others to do the same, i.e. dump their homework and hope someone else does their work for them. Sometimes you help someone the most when you don't help them at all.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider attempting to do your own homework

```
CREATE TABLE computers (serial_number,  manufacturer, model) AS
SELECT 'D123',  'Dell', 'laptop' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D124',  'Dell', 'laptop' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1424',  'Apple', 'laptop' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1425',  'Apple', 'laptop' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1725',  'compaq', 'tower' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1726',  'compaq', 'tower' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1727',  'compaq', 'tower' FROM DUAL;


CREATE TABLE employees (employee_id, manager_id, first_name, last_name, serial_number) AS
SELECT 1, NULL, 'Alice', 'Abbot', 'D123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'Beryl', 'Baron','D124' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'Carol', 'Chase','A1424' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 'Debra', 'Doris','A1425' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 3, 'Emily', 'Evans','C1725' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 3, 'Fiona', 'Frank','C1726' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 6, 'Gemma', 'Grace','C1727' FROM DUAL;


 select
    EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    EMP.FIRST_NAME,
    EMP.LAST_NAME,
    EMP.MANAGER_ID,
    M.FIRST_NAME, 
    M.LAST_NAME,
    EMP.serial_number,
    C.manufacturer,
    C.model
      from
    employees emp
    JOIN computers c ON emp.serial_number = c.serial_number
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employees m ON emp.MANAGER_ID = m.EMPLOYEE_ID
   ORDER BY EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID;

EMPLOYEE_ID    FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME    MANAGER_ID    FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME    SERIAL_NUMBER    MANUFACTURER    MODEL
1    Alice    Abbot     -      -      -     D123    Dell    laptop
2    Beryl    Baron    1    Alice    Abbot    D124    Dell    laptop
3    Carol    Chase    1    Alice    Abbot    A1424    Apple    laptop
4    Debra    Doris    2    Beryl    Baron    A1425    Apple    laptop
5    Emily    Evans    3    Carol    Chase    C1725    compaq    tower
6    Fiona    Frank    3    Carol    Chase    C1726    compaq    tower
7    Gemma    Grace    6    Fiona    Frank    C1727    compaq    tower
```